# Configuration of laravel under apache to avoid public

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I recently installed laravel under a LAMP server, but can't get it to work if I don't specify `public` in the url for another routes than the index.php.

This is my apache site config (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/furbook.com.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName furbook.calhost.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/furbook.com/public"

<Directory "/var/www/html/furbook.com/public">

AllowOverride all

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then created a symbolic link from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`:
`sudo ln -s ../sites-available/furbook.com.conf`

Finally, this is my .htaccess file in `furbook/public`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

With this now I'm able to skip the `public` folder, `localhost/furbook.com` works redirecting to the `public/index.php` as expected.

But the problem is when I try to route an url like `localhost/furbook.com/cats`, then it throws a page not found error. 
If I use `localhost/furbook.com/public/cats`then works as expected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not quite enough information to answer you question 100% authoritatively -- here's my best guess.

> If I use localhost/furbook.com/public/catsthen works as expected

Apache allows you to setup multiple "VirtualHost" configurations on a single server.  A "VirtualHost" is a domain name like `furbook.calhost.com` that points to a specific folder on your computer.  It's called Virtual because, at the time Apache was created, there was a strong bias towards "one host name/one physical server"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName furbook.calhost.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/furbook.com/public"

<Directory "/var/www/html/furbook.com/public">

AllowOverride all

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You have setup a virtual host **for the name `furbook.calhost.com`**

```
ServerName furbook.calhost.com
```

However, in your URL, you're still accessing the system via the name `localhost`.  Accessing via `localhost` means apache will use the default host/site configuration, which (appears to) still be pointing at the folder above root.

Your options

1. Setup local DNS or a host file to have `furbook.calhost.com` point to `127.0.0.1`
2. Change the **default** configuration of your apache system (probably in `httpd.conf`) to point to the `public` folder

Good luck!

(Also, don't forget Apache systems typically require a reset to pickup new configuration changes)

Comment: I went with option 1: edited my `/etc/hosts` and added `127.0.0.1 furbook.com`. Thanks a lot for that and most of all for your explanations :-)